# include and require functions in PHP are not adding contents but not erroring out

Tags: php, include

I'mu using the Codeigniter framework and I have an include_once('filename'); at the beginning of a function. In stepping through the code in debug mode the caller function evaluates the filename properly. I can then actually steps through the file line by line I'm attempting to include. The variables show up as I'm in the included file properly, and as soon as I exit out of the include file and back to the caller function that has the include_once() call, all the data is gone and the variables that were set in 'filename' are uninitialized. What could possibly be causing this type of behavior?

Comment: Could you show us the code you are using?

Comment: I'm not sure if it relates, but there may be something fishy with include(s) in some instances with Codeigniter. I found your question while searching for an answer to my own:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8156743/php-codeigniter-in-centos-include-once-failing-for-custom-system-libraries

Comment: I'm sorry that I abandoned this question. I was new to StackOverflow at the time of asking. I'm not facing this problem anymore but unfortunately have no idea how I resolved it because it was so long ago.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe (i.e., surely) the problem is that, as you said, you're including the file INSIDE A FUNCTION. So, all variables will exist only inside the ***scope*** of that function, and not outside of it.

You could either declare those variables global (which is frowned upon), or better have the function *return* the values you need from the variables of your included file.

Learn more on [PHP Variable scopes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: Sorry for not making it clear, but the i'm using the include inside the same function which I'm attempting to use the included content. When I say caller and callee I mean the function that actually calls the include() function.

Comment: Well, in this case you better provide some code or it would be nearly impossible to spot out errors! Please edit your question adding the function you mention, thanks.